# Derived class with base class as a data member?

Tags: c++, inheritance, composition

I am modelling an population using an agent-based framework. It's generally not important to distinguish between males and females, other than when animals reproduce, in which it is important to have female agents of breeding age. The breeders then must have animals as a data member. I am trying to get the cleanest implementation of this framework, but I am unsure whether my current approach is the best.

I currently have a base class called `Animal`, and a derived class called `Breeder`. `Breeder` has a unique pointer data member denoting their offspring, which is of animal type:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Animal
  {
     private:
       int id_;
      protected:
       int sex_; // 0 = female, 1 = male

      public:
         Animal() {};
         Animal(int id): id_(id) { };
         int get_id() const { return id_; };
};

class Breeder : public Animal {

     public:
       Breeder(int id) : Animal(get_id())
        { 
            sex_ = 0; 
            id_b = id;
        };

    private:
       int id_b;
        std::unique_ptr<Animal> offspring;

    public:
        void give_birth() {
           std::cout << "breeder " << id_b << " is giving birth" << std::endl;
            offspring = std::make_unique<Animal> (id_b+1);
        };
        int get_id_b() { return id_b; };
        int get_offspring_id() { return offspring->get_id(); };
};
```

My problem is that it feels awkward for me to have the derived class with a member variable that is of the base class. Is it awkward?

Also, breeders can access the individual offpsring's public member functions/variables, but presumably the offspring should be able to 'know' their mother, so the base class could have a pointer member to the derived class.

Is there a better way of dealing with this? Maybe two different classes using composition? For instance, should the breeder class have the functionality to give birth?

Comment: Are there any types of animal that will not have offspring?   If not, why does `Breeder` need to be a distinct class?

Comment: It doesn't contain a base class. It contains a pointer. So it has similar semantics to a linked list (If you use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animal>> offsprings` instead, it will be like a tree, representing a family tree).

Comment: Old question of _is a_ / _has a_. Lookup inheritance vs. composition.

Comment: Please note that every time your breeder gives birth you kill an existing offspring...

Comment: @Peter Not all animals are breeders (there are males and females who don't give birth).

Comment: @Artyer Thanks for the clarity. I will be including vectors of pointers soon too to hold multiple offpsring.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Yes, but I couldn't quite find an answer for this specific scenario because the derived class is is pointing towards the base class, and I thought that was particularly awkward.

Comment: @user_15 - That wasn't my question.    I'm aware not every male or female (assuming a two-gender species) does not have offspring.   There are also conditions that may mean an individual does not breed (diseases, injuries, physical conditions, premature death, etc).  But there are no species that do not have the capability to breed if given the opportunity, since that is a path to extinction.   There is nothing special about zero as a number of offspring.

Comment: @Peter I could provide the Animal class with the functionality to breed but later on I might want to distinguish males from females. I guess male and female could be separate classes in that case, but there are times I just want to fill containers of Animal types and don't want to distinguish males and females. I think I need another think through...

Comment: @user_15 -  Yes, you need to rethink your model.   Males and females both breed and have offspring.  Only the mechanism is different.

Comment: @Peter I will do. I was trying to keep it simple, so that I didn't have to model the mechanisms that weren't important to the model. It's not important for the model to track a male's offspring, but it is important to model the breeding cycle and birth/weaning processes of females. So, female animals need to gestate, give birth and wean their offspring. This led me to the derived breeder class.

Answer (score 3):

> My problem is that it feels awkward for me to have the derived class with a member variable that is of the base class. Is it awkward?

Not at all (necessarily). If that fits your domain logic then that could be a very good solution.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I thought it was very circular and an indication that a better structure might be needed.

Comment: It has flexibility, so that it's ready to model things like the usual case where the offspring of a horse and donkey is a non-breeding mule (although [some mares have bred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mule#Fertility)). Or perhaps you're modeling something more fantastical like dragons and donkeys (whose offspring may or may not be breeders).

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly how a linked list of objects should look.

Once you've changed your *one* offspring into a collection of multiple offspringen, it'll be exactly how a tree of objects should look.

Nothing wrong with that at all. Carry on.

---

Minor style suggestion: make `sex_` an `enum class` with `Male` and `Female` members, not an `int` with mapping given only in comments. You'll find it easier to read when your eyes are away from the declaration, and easier to avoid mistakes too.